# Javascript Uncheck all boxes function to Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to figure out how this function would be converted to Vue.  I basically want to uncheck all checked boxes on the page.

```
$("#UncheckAll").click(function(){
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create data property and bind it to a checkbox.  Then your button would modify the property when pressed.

Something like this:

```html
<button @click='isChecked=false'>Uncheck</button>
<input v-model='isChecked' type='checkbox' />
```

In your component options:

```js
data() { 
  return {
    isChecked: false
  }
}
```

Comment: It is currently set to a different v-model from the previous developer. 
 <input :id="filterId('branchFilter', index)" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="filter" v-model="selectFilter" @change="FiltersChanged" />
and the return data is selectFilter:[].

Comment: You have an array of checkboxes?

Comment: Yes. It is an array coming from an api.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    items: [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}, {id: 3, name: 'three'}],
    selected: []
  },
  computed: {
    toggleAll: {
      get: function () {
        return this.items ? this.selected.length == this.items.length : false;
      },
      set: function (value) {
        const selected = [];
        if (value) this.items.forEach((item) => selected.push(item.id));
        this.selected = selected;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="toggleAll" id="all">
  <label for="all" align="left">Toogle all</label>
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="item.id" :id="item.id" number>
    <label :for="item.id">{{ item.name }}</label>
  </li>
</div>
```